# Python - how to parse this with regex correctly? its parsing all the E.164 but except the local format

Tags: python, regex

Its working for 0032, 32, +32 but not as 0487365060 (which is a valid term)

```
  to_user = "0032487365060"
  # ^(?:\+|00)(\d+)$ Parse the 0032, 32, +32 & 0487365060
  match = re.search(r'^(?:\+|00)(\d+)$', to_user)

  to_user = "32487365060"
  match = re.search(r'^(?:\+|00)(\d+)$', to_user)

  to_user = "+32487365060"   
  match = re.search(r'^(?:\+|00)(\d+)$', to_user)
```

Not working:

```
  to_user = "0487365060"   
  match = re.search(r'^(?:\+|00)(\d+)$', to_user)
```

Comment: What does "working" mean? When I try these, the second match is `None`—as you'd expect, since it doesn't have a `00` or `+` at the start. If that's the rule you're trying to write, then the fourth one shouldn't match either. If it isn't, then what _is_ the rule that you want?

Comment: Contrary to what you appear to be saying, your regex does not match `32487365060`.

Comment: https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers

Comment: Also, this isn't technically matching E.164 numbers. A `+` means "dial your country's international call prefix, then the following E.164 number". And `00` doesn't really mean anything, it just happens to be the international call prefix in most of western Europe and some other countries; it's `011` in the US, `010` in Japan, etc. Presumably there _is_ some specific standard or convention that you're trying to capture, but you have to know what it is before you can capture it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last example doesn't work because it does not start with either `+` or `00`. If that is *optional* you need to mark it as such:

```
r'^(?:\+|00)?(\d+)$'
```

Note that neither does your *second* example match; it doesn't start with `+` or `00` *either*.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> samples = ('0032487365060', '32487365060', '+32487365060', '0487365060')
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'^(?:\+|00)?(\d+)$')
>>> for sample in samples:
...     match = pattern.search(sample)
...     if match is not None:
...         print 'matched:', match.group(1)
...     else:
...         print 'Sample {} did not match'.format(sample)
... 
matched: 32487365060
matched: 32487365060
matched: 32487365060
matched: 0487365060
```

Comment: But that makes his second example—which he claims is already working as intended—return `32487365060` instead of `None`. (I suspect this is what he actually wants, but it's not what he's saying…)

Comment: @abarnert: yes, the question is rather.. confused.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to know which method was matched? so that when i have 0032 i can replace it as 32 when i have +32 i can replace it to 32 when i have 32 i can keep it as 32 and when i have 0487365060 i can replace it to 32487365060? The match is working perfectly, thinking now how to understand which method was it matched.

Comment: If you made the first group capturing (by removing the `?:`, leaving just `(\+|00)?`, then you can access what was matched as group 1, and group 2 is the rest of the digits. The. You can base your logic off of that.

Answer (score 0):

Taking account of the question AND the comment, and in absence of more info (particularly on the length of the sequence of digits that must follow the 32 part, and if it is always 32 or may be another sequence), what I finally understand you want cab be obtained with:

```
import re

for to_user in  ("0032487365060",
                 "32487365060",
                 "+32487365060",
                 "0487365060"):  
    m = re.sub('^(?:\+32|0032|32|0)(\d{9})$','32\\1', to_user)
    print m
```

Comment: Perfect. Wish i could click Answer as twice. This is what exactly i was trying. Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you sure you always finally want 32 in front of 9 subsequent digits ? If not, my answer won't fit

Comment: Please see: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6557938/  , not always 9 subsequent digits. Also like you did for 32, i need to do it for all the international country codes. Does it mean i have to make a long list like 32 for all worldwide code numbers?

Comment: Your theory is perfect. but any + or any 00 should be removed so it it becomes 00 less and + less, only 048 patterns should be 32 added like you did. Excellent way you have done it, i am getting now confused how do i deal so many codes in small regex rules.

Comment: In (http://www.csoft.co.uk/phone_numbers/) I see that the IFTN (International Format Telephone Number) is 12 digits for UK. While you wrote ``"4412345678"`` for the IFTN in UK

Comment: YES - you are right. But i need to do a inbound parse and then outbound send, what-ever is in inbound i have to accept it and follow the way i show in my answer, updated based on your idea/theory.

Comment: Your goal is confused from the beginning. What do you want to do, in the end ? It seems you want to build a function that transforms a telephone number expressed with + or 00 at the beginning, to an ITFN. But trying to make this function to return the inputed number if there is already the TCC (Telephonic Country Code) in front, or to transform a local tel number with beginning replaced with the TCC (of the country in which the local number is practiced) in any other case, is illusory: there's certainly cases in which a TCC can't be deduced from the format of a local number, and....

Comment: ...there are certainly local numbers that begin with same digit sequence as one of the Tel Country Codes

Comment: The only solution I see is to put in the code a snippet that ask either the desired country's name or a confirmation on the deduced country's code. It is also necessary to collect all the TCC for all the countries for which the program may be used.

Comment: Thank you. I think your solution is enough and a little modification like my answer solved my problem. thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this @eyquem method, to cover all the international codes from + and 00 into without +, 00 only for Belgium it should be default 32+the number:

```
import re

for to_user in  (# Belgium  
                 "0032487365060",
                 "32487365060",
                 "+32487365060",
                 "0487365060",
                 # USA
                 "0012127773456",
                 "12127773456",
                 "+12127773456",
                 # UK
                 "004412345678", 
                 "4412345678", 
                 "+4412345678"):  
    m = re.sub('^(?:\+|00|32|0)(\d{9})$','32\\1', to_user)
    m = m.replace("+","")
    m = re.sub('^(?:\+|00)(\d+)$', '\\1', m)
    print m
```

Output:

```
32487365060
32487365060
32487365060
32487365060
12127773456
12127773456
12127773456
4412345678
4412345678
4412345678
```

Execution Successful!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use the program only for USA, Belgium, and UK countries ?

Comment: BTW what aboutthe fact that your example with UK'number doesn't correspond to the number of digit in the ITFN given in this pasge for UK: (http://www.csoft.co.uk/phone_numbers/) ???

Comment: I will be able to deal all the international numbers with this method now. In my condition its not important to follow the ITFN because i have to capture the number and filter it as no + sign, no 00

Comment: OK. I think the game is over, so :)

Comment: Thank you so much, without your idea it was impossible to get the correct direction. Genius!!

Comment: N'exagérons rien :) Dis-donc, tu dois parler français si tu es belge. - J'ai regardé le site Tizen, ça a l'air d'être un projet balèze et important: géré par la Linux Foundation ! Tu participes au développement de ce logiciel Tizen ?

Comment: oui en effet, je suis là Contributeur trop, son mieux en mieux

Comment: Euh, j'ai un peu de mal à comprendre ce français là... :) Allez salut.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use  [phonenumbers](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers) lib

```
>>> phonenumbers.parse("0487365060", "BE")
PhoneNumber(country_code=32, national_number=487365060, extension=None, italian_leading_zero=None, number_of_leading_zeros=None, country_code_source=0, preferred_domestic_carrier_code=None)
```

and other 3 is ok to

```
>>> phonenumbers.parse("0032487365060", "BE")
PhoneNumber(country_code=32, national_number=487365060, extension=None, italian_leading_zero=None, number_of_leading_zeros=None, country_code_source=0, preferred_domestic_carrier_code=None)
>>> phonenumbers.parse("+320487365060", "BE")
PhoneNumber(country_code=32, national_number=487365060, extension=None, italian_leading_zero=None, number_of_leading_zeros=None, country_code_source=0, preferred_domestic_carrier_code=None)
>>> phonenumbers.parse("320487365060", "BE")
PhoneNumber(country_code=32, national_number=487365060, extension=None, italian_leading_zero=None, number_of_leading_zeros=None, country_code_source=0, preferred_domestic_carrier_code=None)
```